# Can we use React js for beacon detection

Tags: reactjs

I am working on beacon detection and want to find it using React js. Can we do the same ? If not can anyone suggest how can i achieve it ? I tried searching but didn't find anything relatde to it.

Comment: What's beacon detection?

Comment: Beacon detection means knowing the presense of beacon in a range.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibeacon

You mean something like this?

Comment: Unfortunately this is out of date & doesn't look like it is maintained anymore :(

Comment: Have a look again. I think someone else is now maintaining this lib